# Carousel shows perfectly , but wont slide

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

help me debug my php code for carousel, it wont slide away, what do i miss ?
i want it to autoslide when the page load,nevermind that it wont slide when i clicked the indicators.

```
echo '<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';
    echo '
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>';

    echo '<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">';

    echo '<div class="item active">';
    echo '<div class="jumbotron" style="border:solid 3px;height:500px;margin-top:20px">';   
    echo '<div class="containeractive  col-md-6"
         style="height:400px;border:solid 2px; margin: 0px 50px 10px 20px;
         background-image:url('.$row['image'].');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain; background-position:center"></div>';
    echo '<div class="container col-md-5" style="height:85px;border:solid 3px;margin-bottom:30px">'.$row['name'].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="container col-md-5" style="height: 285px; border:solid 3px;">'.$row['description'].'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    mysqli_data_seek($result,1);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);

    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo '<div class="jumbotron" style="border:solid 3px;height:500px;margin-top:20px">';   
    echo '<div class="container col-md-6"
         style="height:400px;border:solid 2px; margin: 0px 50px 10px 20px;
         background-image:url('.$row2['image'].');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain; background-position:center"></div>';
    echo '<div class="container col-md-5" style="height:85px;border:solid 3px;margin-bottom:30px">'.$row2['name'].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="container col-md-5" style="height: 285px; border:solid 3px;">'.$row2['description'].'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Have you included a link to Bootstrap's JavaScript file on your page? https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add javascript of bootstrap. Just add this in end of body section

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```